# Extract Uniqe Values from Multiple Lists

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching around for a VBA code that consolidates multiple columns of similar items, into one unique list of items. I have seen code that you can put into the actual excel workbook; however, I see on my excel spreadsheet it is very slow to run considering that I have 120,000+ lines. My excel spreadsheet looks like:

```
List1    List2    List3
AAASB    AAASB    AAASB
AAASF    AAASC    AAASF
AAASJ    AAASF    AAASJ
AAASV    AAASJ    AAATQ
AAATB    AAATD    AAATD
AAATD             AAAAC
AAATE             AAATE
                  AAAAD
```

So the new list would have items AAASB, AAASF, AAATD, and AAASJ because those 4 items are in all three lists.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Sana. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a helper column? You could just have a formula like this:

`=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,C2)>=1,COUNTIF(B:B,C2)>=1),TRUE,FALSE)`

You could then filter by `TRUE` to show only the values in column C that also occur at least once in both column A and B.